# Fail to connect to WSL2 via ssh

Tags: ssh, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have managed to connect to WSL2(win11) once on my MacBook.
Then I restart windows machine to test ssh connection.
But in this time, it fails, reporting
`kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

I've already added `sshd: ALL` in WSL and restart ssh service.
But I still cannot connect to WSL.
What can I do?

Comment: What is your purpose for ssh'ing from Mac to WSL2?  My recommended setup steps for ssh are slightly different depending on your needs.  Do you just need terminal access to your Windows machine through WSL2 from your Mac?  Or something more like `scp`?

Comment: Actually, I want to use WSL2 as a linux server.

Answer (score 0):

When rebooted WSL would pick a different IP, making your port forwarding settings invalid because packets will be forwarded to the old IP address which doesn't exist on your system anymore. You'd need to use some form of bridge more or static IP. Also [scripting the setup](https://gist.github.com/daehahn/497fa04c0156b1a762c70ff3f9f7edae?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) might be helpful too.

[Hanselman talked about this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-ssh-into-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine) in more detail as well:

> FORWARD PORTS INTO WSL2
>
> Now, from an Administrator Windows prompt - that can be cmd.exe or powershell.exe, it doesn't matter, use the net shell "netsh" to add a portproxy rule. Again, change connectaddress to **YOUR WSL2 ipaddress**, which is an internal address to your machine.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 listenport=2222 connectaddress=<internal-IP> connectport=2222
```

As **YOUR WSL2 ipaddress** changes next boot, port forwarding stops working.

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Ive already done that before. It does not work.